# PowerShell: Batch File Renaming underscore to hyphen

Tags: pdf, powershell, batch

Is it possible using PowerShell (Windows 7) to target a specific delimiter within a file name and change that delimiter from say underscores to hyphens/dashes?

For instance:

```
1942.009.405_SIENESE 16TH CENTURY__1988_09_08_DATA REPORT_TX_4305010_0002.pdf
```

to

```
1942.009.405_SIENESE 16TH CENTURY__1988-09-08_DATA REPORT_TX_4305010_0002.pdf
```

If the date in the file name is missing or a part of the date were missing would any command prompt used be able to handle this anomaly?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have to tell if a badly formed date is enclosed in `**` and how to proceed then.

Comment: Am I missing something? The original post did not have the `**` around the date. @Toto, why did you add those?

Comment: @EBGreen: Sorry, I forgot remove them :(

Comment: All good. I'm just easily confused you know.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change all the underscores to dashes, you can do this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_','-' }
```

Take a look at [example 4 from the official docs on `Rename-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1#example-4--rename-multiple-files).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression replacement:

```
$test = '1942.009.405_SIENESE 16TH CENTURY__1988_09_08_DATA REPORT_TX_4305010_0002.pdf'
$test -replace '^(.+\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2}.+)$', '$1-$2-$3'
```

This finds all of the characters up to a four digit number, then the underscore, then a two digit number, then another underscore, then a two digit number and the rest of the characters. It then replaces everything with the first bit that it found `$1 = (.+\d{4})` a dash the second bit `$2 = (\d{2})` another dash then everything else `$3 = (\d{2}.+)`